# Sorting NSCollectionViews bound Array Controller -> Explicitly Animate NSCollectionViewItems frame

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, appkit, nscollectionview

I have an NSCollectionView which is bound to an NSArrayController via Interface Builder.

I provide NSSortDescriptors and NSPredicates to filter and sort the array (which totally works), however, since I am relying on the implicit animation via NSAnimationContext the only key my CALayers are requested to animate is @"hidden". I would like to animate the frame origin so the cells visually move to their new positions.

In the past I've used the collection views animator property to performBatchUpdate's and animate insertions, deletions and moves which resulted in @"frameOrigin" animations to be triggered. It doesnt seem to work that way using bindings?

Is it possible when specifying a sort or filter on the ArrayController which is backing my NSCollectionView via binding, to force explicit frame animation on its items?

Here is my current sorting code, for reference:

```
- (void) setupSortUsingSortDescriptor:(NSSortDescriptor*) sortDescriptor selectedItem:(SynopsisMetadataItem*)item
{
    NSAnimationContext.currentContext.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
    NSAnimationContext.currentContext.duration = 0.5;
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];

    self.resultsArrayControler.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [self updateStatusLabel];

    if(item != nil)
    {
        NSUInteger index = [self.resultsArrayControler.arrangedObjects indexOfObject:item];
        if(index != NSNotFound)
        {
             NSIndexPath* newItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0];

             NSSet* newItemSet = [NSSet setWithCollectionViewIndexPath:newItem];

            [self.resultsArrayControler setSelectionIndex:index];

            [self.collectionView.animator scrollToItemsAtIndexPaths:newItemSet scrollPosition:NSCollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically];
        }    
    }
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}
```

Thanks, any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to help without seeing all the code and settings for Collection View. It could have different styles and layout. Collection View with "content array" layout animates items out of the box as soon as you change sortDescriptors of bound NSArrayController.

I created an example for you in Swift (cannot do objective-c sorry):

https://github.com/emankovski/AnmatedCollectionSort